# Converting mysql_result into msqli

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to convert mysql_result into into mysqli. There is not a equal conversion for it.

```
$total_items = mysql_result(mysql_query($con,' SELECT FOUND_ROWS(); '), 0, 0);    
$this->items = $data;
```

Answer (score 1):

The deprecated `mysql_result` equals the new mysqli command `mysqli_fetch_field`. You can find exampled in the php.net documentation. For example non-object-oriented:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, SurfaceArea from Country ORDER BY Code LIMIT 5";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* Get field information for all fields */
    while ($finfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {

        printf("Name:     %s\n", $finfo->name);
        printf("Table:    %s\n", $finfo->table);
        printf("max. Len: %d\n", $finfo->max_length);
        printf("Flags:    %d\n", $finfo->flags);
        printf("Type:     %d\n\n", $finfo->type);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

[mysqli_fetch_field](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php)